# How can i do consumption by location in Azure using az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to do consumption by location using:

```
  az login
  $consumpCost = az consumption usage list --query "[? 
  type=='Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails' && 
  instanceLocation=='northcentralus'].pretaxCost" --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
  $consumpCost = $consumpCost -split "`n" | ForEach-Object { [decimal]$_ }
  $combcost = $consumpCost | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
  Write-Host "Total Cost: $combcost"
```

But it always comes out 0.00 in total ie $combcost .
Can anyone help as to why it is coming out as $0.00 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the unnecessary lines of code such as `split` operator and place holders as it might lead to conflicts in displaying the correct results.

***Modified Script:***

```
$usageDetails = az consumption usage list --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails' && instanceLocation=='US East'].pretaxCost" --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
$consumpCost = $usageDetails | ForEach-Object { [decimal]$_ }
$combcost = $consumpCost | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
Write-Host "Total Cost: $combcost"
```

***Note:*** At times, if the `Total Cost` appears as `0`, it doesn't necessarily indicate an issue with the results. It could be that the specified `location` in your query is not actively used by any users or applications within the particular enterprise agreement. In such scenarios, consider trying other locations to validate the details.

After I executed the above code in my environment, I was able to retrieve the cost consumption details successfully.

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have ran this locally and still get the error :   ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version.

Comment: do i need to append the --api-version anywhere ?

Comment: is it the version of Poershell ? I am running it from Windows Powershell ISE

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as `Run as administrator`. ? @Melissa

Comment: And also login into the azure account with `az login` command and then execute the code. @Melissa

Comment: yes i am running as adminitrator and using az login. Now is there something in the Azure portal i need to set in my subscription ?

Comment: Do you have an `Account administrator` or `Enterprise Administrator` set on the subscription? @Melissa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257017/discussion-between-melissa-and-jahnavi).